# Not able to comprehend the error from httpie call

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, http

I am trying to call this API from the python console and getting the following error. I have tried reinstalling the Httpie package, but in vain. I can't comprehend the error. What might cause this error?
Any help will be truly helpful.
I am using python 3.x in a windows server environment. Thanks!

```
C:\Users\CXXXXX>http --auth-type=veracode_hmac "https://analysiscenter
.veracode.com/api/5.0/getappinfo.do" "app_id=="%1 > getappinfo.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python38-32\lib\site-packages\httpie\config.py", line 47, in load
    data = json.load(f)
  File "d:\python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "d:\python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "d:\python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "d:\python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "d:\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Python38-32\Scripts\http.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "d:\python38-32\lib\site-packages\httpie\__main__.py", line 11, in main
    sys.exit(main())
  File "d:\python38-32\lib\site-packages\httpie\core.py", line 193, in main
    if env.config.default_options:
  File "d:\python38-32\lib\site-packages\httpie\context.py", line 84, in config
    self._config.load()
  File "d:\python38-32\lib\site-packages\httpie\config.py", line 96, in load
    super(Config, self).load()
  File "d:\python38-32\lib\site-packages\httpie\config.py", line 49, in load
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Invalid Config JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) [\\ci
fs.nas1.us2.experian.corp\CitrixUPM\Folders\C63639A\AppData\Roaming\\httpie\conf
ig.json]
```

Comment: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` - The "json" is empty, hence it can't be parsed (fails on the beginning, expecting value but got nothing). Had similar problem in `requests` library - check returned code for 204 (which means the request was ok but no content was returned) before trying to convert or try/catch this thing (catching would mean you can omit some other problem that can manifest as `JSONDecodeError`).

Comment: Sorry for the prev comment. The problem seems to be when you **init** the `httpie`. It still is the problem with non-existent json, but it won't be about checking return code (because the problem happens before you even send any request). Check the file it says and find in the docs how to use your config.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But the same command was working fine and it was returning result. Then I tried to use multiprocessing, but that failed. After that I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

hank you for pointing to the JSON. It solved the problem. I think some how the json got corrupted. I deleted the json and rerun the command and it worked.